# How to make *Buffer List* appear below the other windows?

Tags: emacs

So, instead of creating a split window under (or to the right of) the currently active window, it would appear below all the existed ones with a half of the frame height? And, after closing, frame layout would be restored as it was before calling C-x C-b?

I’d like see the full paths to opened files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also my previous answer to your related issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21544307/2112489

See also a related answer by @phils, which includes a nice `halve-other-window-height` function:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988206/2112489

See also the built-in stock functions `display-buffer-below-selected` or `display-buffer-at-bottom`, which are available in a recent version of Emacs Trunk -- I'm not sure when each function was first introduced.  They are in `window.el`.

The doc-string of the function `split-window` states in relevant part:  *SIZE defaults to half of
WINDOW's size*.  That is the second optional argument -- i.e., `split-window (&optional window size side pixelwise)`

Don't be shy about modifying these things -- you can make it do whatever you want.  If want to select the window automatically after it is displayed, then you can add this to the bottom of the `lawlist-display-buffer-below` function:  `(select-window (get-buffer-window (buffer-name buffer)))` -- leaving, of course, two closing parenthesis to the right -- i.e., one closing parentheis for the `let` binding and one closing parenthesis for the `defun`.

```
(defun lawlist-list-buffers-below (&optional arg)
  "Display a list of existing buffers.
The list is displayed in a buffer named \"*Buffer List*\".
See `buffer-menu' for a description of the Buffer Menu.
    By default, all buffers are listed except those whose names start
with a space (which are for internal use).  With prefix argument
ARG, show only buffers that are visiting files."
  (interactive "P")
  (lawlist-display-buffer-below (list-buffers-noselect arg) nil))

(defun lawlist-display-buffer-below (buffer alist)
 (let (
    (window
      (cond
        ((get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame)))
        ((window-in-direction 'below))
        (t
          (split-window (selected-window) nil 'below)))))
  (window--display-buffer buffer window 'window alist display-buffer-mark-dedicated)))
```