# Reverse evaluation order of split-height-threshold and split-width-threshold in Emacs for display-buffer

Tags: emacs, emacs24

When `display-buffer` has to create a new window in an existing pane, the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html) states that `split-height-threshold` is looked at first to determine if the new window can be below the current one, **then** `split-width-threshold` is evaluated in the same way for side-by-side windows.

Is there a way to make Emacs try first to put the windows side by side first if the width is high enough? I can set `split-height-threshold` to `nil` to inhibit vertical split altogether, but that makes Emacs steal another window if the current one is not wide enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make Emacs do this by customizing the variable `split-window-preferred-function`:

```lisp
(defun my-split-window-sensibly (&optional window)
  (let ((window (or window (selected-window))))
    (or (and (window-splittable-p window t)
             ;; Split window horizontally.
             (with-selected-window window
               (split-window-right)))
        (and (window-splittable-p window)
             ;; Split window vertically.
             (with-selected-window window
               (split-window-below)))
        (and (eq window (frame-root-window (window-frame window)))
             (not (window-minibuffer-p window))
             ;; If WINDOW is the only window on its frame and is not the
             ;; minibuffer window, try to split it horizontally disregarding
             ;; the value of `split-width-threshold'.
             (let ((split-width-threshold 0))
               (when (window-splittable-p window t)
                 (with-selected-window window
                   (split-window-right))))))))

(setq split-window-preferred-function 'my-split-window-sensibly)
```

The variable `split-window-preferred-function`

> specifies a function for splitting a window, in order to make a new window for displaying a buffer.  It is used by the `display-buffer-pop-up-window` action function to actually split the window.

By default, it is set to `split-window-sensibly`. The function I am providing above is a modified version of `split-window-sensibly` (defined in [`window.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/window.el)) that simply reverses the steps of the original function, causing Emacs to "prefer" side-by-side window splits over stacked ones.