# Customize window splitting in emacs python-mode

Tags: user-interface, emacs, elisp

Every time I send a line to python console in emacs python-mode,
it executes split-window-below, like this:

[image]

On most computer screen the vertical dimension is stringent,
thus it's more desireable to trigger split-window-right instead,
like this:

[image]

This can be done manually (c-x 1 c-x 3 c-x o c-x b), but once
you execute any python code from your source file, the layout
returns to the annoying one.

Is there a way to customize this persistently?

---

Edit:

I have tried a few things, including the answer suggested in the
comment below. So far it looks the following lines in .emacs
"sort of" work:

```
(setq split-height-threshold nil)
(setq split-width-threshold 0)
```

except that they will make an extra window below:

[image]

Comment: Please see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23663761/1199226) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23659909/1199226) for a general-purpose solution for telling Emacs to prefer side-by-side window splits over stacked ones. If you want to customize behavior for `python-mode` buffers *only*, you can simply wrap the call to `setq` (last line of the code in the answer) in a function: `(defun prefer-side-by-side-splits () ...)` and add that function to `python-mode-hook` via `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'prefer-side-by-side-splits)`.

Comment: I tried that one, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the fact that your modeline contains `Py` as a major mode indicator I am assuming you are using [`python-mode.el`](https://launchpad.net/python-mode/) instead of the built-in `python.el`. This package defines a variable called `py-split-windows-on-execute-function` that allows you to specify which function to use for splitting windows when calling a command from the `py-execute-*` family.

To make horizontal (side-by-side) splitting the default for windows displaying `python-mode` buffers, add the following to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(require 'python-mode)
(setq-default py-split-windows-on-execute-function 'split-window-horizontally)
```

Note that you have to use `setq-default` instead of `setq` because `py-split-windows-on-execute-function` is a [buffer-local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer_002dLocal-Variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

Or, in addition to what itsjeyd said, just:

```
M-x customize-variable RET py-split-windows-on-execute-function RET
```

Then select from "Value Menu"

Comment: This is really nice. Is there something similar for ESS mode?

Comment: @qed Don't know. Maybe file a new question?